# Sum of series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n\left(1 + 2^{{1}/{2^n}}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math, power-series

Taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm5az_95nQs

I'm having trouble solving the following problem:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n\left(1 + 2^{{1}/{2^n}}\right)} = a + \frac{b}{\ln(c)}.$$ Find $a, b$ and $c.$

It kinda looks like a power series with $x=1/2$, but I can't find anything about coefficients of form $\frac{1}{1+2^{\theta_n}}$. And logarithm on RHS really puzzles me. I also tried the following: $$\frac{1}{2^n(1 + 2^{2^{-n}})} = \frac{1 + 2^{2^{-n}}- 2^{2^{-n}}}{2^n(1 + 2^{2^{-n}})} = 1/2^n - \frac{2^{2^{-n}}}{2^n(1 + 2^{2^{-n}})}$$
in hopes of obtaining a sum (or sums) of geometric series, which, rearranged, may be easier to summate than the original series, but that didn't yield any results.

Comment: I kind of want it to be relevant that $\frac1{2^{2^{-n}}+1} = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (2^{2^{-k}}-1)$, but I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @GregMartin When $n=1$, $\sqrt{2}-1 = 1$?

Comment: Failed to mention where this problem is from

Comment: Quick numerical search finds $a=-1, b=1, c=2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n (x^{2^{-k}}+1)=\frac{x-1}{x^{2^{-n}}-1}$$

$$\frac{f_n'(x)}{f_n(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{-k}x^{2^{-k}-1}}{x^{2^{-k}}+1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{-k}x^{-1}}{1+x^{-2^{-k}}}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-k}}{1+2^{2^{-k}}}=\frac12 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f_n'(1/2)}{f_n(1/2)}=\frac12 \lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac1{-1/2}- \frac{2^{-n} (1/2)^{2^{-n}-1}}{(1/2)^{2^{-n}}-1})$$
$$=\frac12 \lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac1{-1/2}- \frac{2^{-n} (1/2)^{-1}(1+o(1))}{2^{-n}\log(1/2)(1+o(1))})=-1+\frac1{\log 2}$$